# What does this dot syntax mean in the Pebble watch development tutorial?

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

I came across following code in Pebble watch app development tutorial:

```
// Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
  window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });
```

I cant understand this assignment to .load and .unload. Is this standard C? I don't think I have ever seen similar syntax before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is standard c99.

It is combining compound literals

```
 (WindowHandlers) {}
```

and designated initializers

```
.load = main_window_load,
.unload = main_window_unload
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is standard C99, with an initialized `struct` constant with named fields in its initialization.

BTW, it is also a C extension -w.r.t. older C standards- ([designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)) provided by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

For [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard, its final draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes that syntax in "§6.7.9 Initializations"

Comment: "Also a C extension" is confusing and makes it sound like this is not standard, contrary to reality. Did you mean to say GCC also offers it as an extension for older versions of C? Or something else?