# What is this C function syntax?

Tags: c, function, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, procedural-programming

I'd say I have intermediate experience with programming in c, however I've never seen this syntax used before to make a function. This reminds me of the syntax for a JQuery event. Overall, I'd like a detailed explanation of what this is and what the alternative syntax could be.A link to where I could read more about this in particular would be great too.

```
 // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
 window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });
```

This is a code snippet from the [Pebble WatchApp tutorial](https://developer.pebble.com/tutorials/watchface-tutorial/part1).

Comment: I think it's making a struct, casting to `WindowHandlers`, and passing it into that function

Comment: @Alex - No it's instead a compound literal. And btw this is a function call AFAIK. No function is made but instead one is called. The second function argument is a compound literal.

Comment: `window_set_window_handlers` have 2 parameters `s_main_window` and  a struct `WindowHandlers`, the struct `WindowHandlers`  is initialized here

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD I worded it badly. That's basically what I meant. I was drawing parallels from C++'s initialization lists but didn't know what it was called

Comment: @Alex: There is no cast in a compound literal. A cast is a completely different beast.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Again, I knew nothing about compound literals. It looked like a mix of init list and a cast. I figured that it yielded a `WindowHandler`. That's the only thing I was sure of. When I wrote that there was a cast, it was more of a fuzzy thing that I absentmindedly tossed in as I made further guesses. Not meant to be taken seriously

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner: Stop YELLING! And learn C, it **is** C - and very strictly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a function call making use of a compound literal.  It is equivalent to the following:

```
WindowHandlers temp = {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  };
window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, temp );
```

The above also makes use of designated initializers, where you can specify fields to initialize by name.

Assuming `WindowHandlers` contains only `load` and `unload` in that order, the above is equivalent to:

```
WindowHandlers temp = { main_window_load, main_window_unload };
window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, temp );
```

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) goes into these in more detail.

From section 6.5.2.5:

> **4** A postfix  expression  that  consists  of  a  parenthesized  type 
>   name  followed  by  a  brace-enclosed  list  of  initializers  is  a
>   *compound  literal*.  It provides  an  unnamed  object  whose value is
>   given by the initializer list.
>
> ...
>
> **9** EXAMPLE 1  The file scope definition
>
> ```
> int *p = (int []){2, 4};
> ```
>
> initializes `p` to  point  to  the  first  element  of  an  array  of 
>   two ints,  the  first  having  the  value  two and  the second,  four.
>   The  expressions  in  this  compound  literal  are  required  to  be 
>   constant. The  unnamed  object has static storage duration.

From section 6.7.8:

> **1**
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     assignment-expression
>     { initializer-list }
>     { initializer-list , }
> initializer-list:
>     designationopt initializer
>     initializer-list , designationopt initializer
> designation:
>     designator-list =
> designator-list:
>     designator 
>     designator-list  designator
> designator:
>     [ constant-expression ]
>     .identifier
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **7** If a designator has the form
>
> ```
> .identifier
> ```
>
> then  the  current  object  (defined  below)  shall  have  structure 
>   or  union  type  and  the identifier shall be the name of a member of
>   that type.
>
> ...
>
> **34** EXAMPLE 10   Structure members can be initialized to nonzero values without depending on their order:
>
> ```
> div_t answer = { .quot = 2, .rem = -1 };
> ```

Comment: Could you explain what the leading periods mean on variables?

Comment: @user1717828 They specify which fields in the struct being initialized are to be set.

Answer (score 5):

This is standard from C99 onwards.  It is combining compound literals:

```
(WindowHandlers) {}
```

and designated initializers:

```
.load = main_window_load,
.unload = main_window_unload
```

See the link
[What does this dot syntax mean in the Pebble watch development tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949319/is-this-standard-c)

Comment: Well, it is standard C, **introduced** with C99 (but still valid).